# Dropzone.js removedfile event callback - parent dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone in my project and I need to delete files from a folder when clicked on the remove button. I create the dropzones with this:

```
$('.dropzone').dropzone(
{
    init: function ()
    {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) 
        {
            console.log($(file.previewTemplate)); 

            console.log(file.previewTemplate.children[7].value);

            //$.post("delete-file.php?id=" + file.serverId); // Send the file id along
        });
    }
});
```

My dropzone HTML is:

```
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" data-uploadPath="the/path/here/" data-multipleUpload="true"></div>
```

Now, the file parameter contains the previewTemplate of the file. I want to get the/path/here/ by the parents, but if I use:

```
file.previewTemplate.parentNode
```

It returns undefined, why doesn't parentNode work?

Comment: Good question! Would love to get the parent or form of the deleted file too :)
Maybe a data-attribute on the previewTemplate?

Comment: just try console.log(this) within your removedfile event, it gave me the corresponding form element, from there you should get what you want right?

Answer (score 17):

If you override `removedFile` function, then need to manually remove preview of image. Dropzone will not automatically remove file preview.

```
removedfile: function (file) {
    file.previewElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: You should contribute to their documentation, it's currently not maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I faced a similar problem, and based on the comments on your question, I figured out the solution.

The arguments are of no use, but the context 'this' is.
this.element returns the respective dropzone element. In my case, I needed to find the enclosing form element. Hence, all I needed to do was

```
var $form = $(this.element).closest('form');
```